# Escaping separator in data while bulk loading using importtsv tool and ingesting numeric values

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am using importtsv tool to ingest data. I have some doubts. I am using hbase 1.1.5.

First does it ingest non-string/numeric values? I was referring this link detailing importtsv in cloudera distribution. It says:"it interprets everything as strings". So I was guessing what does that mean.

I am using simple wordcount example where first column is a word and second column is word count.

When I keep file as follows:

```
"access","1" 
"about","1"
```

and ingest and then do scan on hbase shell it gives following output:

```
about                                 column=f:count, timestamp=1467716881104, value="1" 
access                                column=f:count, timestamp=1467716881104, value="1"
```

When I keep file as follows (double quotes surrounding count is removed):

```
"access",1 
"about",1
```

and ingest and then do scan on hbase shell it gives following output (double quotes surrounding count is not there):

```
about                                 column=f:count, timestamp=1467716881104, value=1 
access                                column=f:count, timestamp=1467716881104, value=1
```

So as you can see there are no double quotes in count's value.

**Q1.** Does that mean it is stored as integer and not as string?  The cloudera's article suggests that custom MR job needs to be written for ingesting non-string values. However I am not able to get what does that mean if above is ingesting integer values.

Also another doubt I am having is that whether I can escape the column separator when it appears inside the column value. For example in importtsv, we can specify the separator as follows:

```
-Dimporttsv.separator=,
```

However what if I have employee data where first column is employee name and second column as address? My file will have rows resembling to something like this:

```
"mahesh","A6,Hyatt Appartment"
```

That second comma makes importtsv think that there are three columns and throwing `BadTsvLineException("Excessive columns")`.

Thus I tried escaping comma with backslash (`\`) and just for sake of curiosity escaping backslash with another backslash (that is `\\`). So my file had following lines:

```
"able","1\" 
"z","1\" 
"za","1\\1"
```

When I ran scan on hbase shell, it gave following output:

```
able                                  column=f:count, timestamp=1467716881104, value="1\x5C" 
z                                     column=f:count, timestamp=1467716881104, value="1\x5C" 
za                                    column=f:count, timestamp=1467716881104, value="1\x5C\x5C1"
```

**Q2.** So it seems that instead of escaping character following backslash, it encodes backslash as `\x5C`. Is it like that? Is there no way to escape column separator while bulk loading data using importtsv?

Comment: I am finding the same issues. My impression is that importtsv is not able to properly handle quoted csv files. Did you figure out any solution?

Comment: we needed to write custom hbase map reduce for bulk import. Something like these: [1](http://www.rswebsols.com/tutorials/programming/bulk-load-big-data-hadoop-hbase-table), [2](https://sreejithrpillai.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/bulkloading-data-into-hbase-table-using-mapreduce/)

Comment: Yes, I'm going to write a custom implementation too. Thanks!

Comment: [This link](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-use-hbase-bulk-loading-and-why/) also helped me.